# Сохранение значения editText после перехода обратно в Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть два активити. В первом активити есть editText поле, в котором есть значение, далее идет кнопка, которая перекидывает во второе активити. Во втором активити есть кнопка, которая возвращает в первое активити с editText. Вот вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы после ухода во второе активити, текст в editField сохранился после возвращения в него.

Уже пробовал и через savedInstance и через метод onResume.

Вот код:

```
 AppCompatButton translateButton;
AppCompatButton chooseLanguageButton;
AppCompatButton visionPageButton;
AppCompatTextView translatedTextOutput;
AppCompatEditText translatedTextInput;
String translatedInputString;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
String savedInstance;




final String TAG = "myTag";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    translateButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    chooseLanguageButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.choose_language_button);
    visionPageButton = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.vision_page_button);
    translatedTextOutput = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.translated_text_field);
    translatedTextInput = (AppCompatEditText) findViewById(R.id.translation_input_edit);

    translateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Inside onClick");
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
            sendJsonRequest();
        }
    });

    chooseLanguageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChooseLanguageList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    visionPageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Vision.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    savedInstance = translatedTextInput.getText().toString();
    Log.v("Tag", "Saved Instand " + savedInstance.toString());
    outState.putString("savedInput", savedInstance);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(outState);
    Log.v("tag", "Inside on restore");
   translatedTextInput.setText(outState.getString("savedInput"));
}
```

Comment: "кнопка, которая возвращает в первое активити" -- можно увидеть код этого возврата?

Comment: Назначьте переменную с методом получения значений c `EditText` и сохраняйте в `SharedPreferences`. Затем в методе `onCreate` задайте setText для вашего `EditText` и передавайте туда эту переменную.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема скорее всего заключается в том, что вторая активити стартует первую через интент, т.е. создает новый экземпляр первой активити. а если активити новая, то и edittext будет новым.

Это можно легко проверить.

На второй активити вместо своей кнопки нажмите на кнопку back. Вы вернетесь к предыдущей активити, edittext должен быть не пустой.
Вариант решения такой: во второй активити не стартовать интентом первую, а вызвать finish() (вторая активити умрет, и бекстек вернет вас на первую)

Comment: Это как лечить головную боль топором. Но да, поможет.

Comment: Спасибо. Но там через intent.putExtras забираются данные из нажатой кнопки, которые используются в первой активити. Поэтому через интент.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Решил вопрос через sharedPreferences. Внизу образец кода

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос через SharedPreferences.
Вот код

```
void saveText() {
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, translatedTextInput.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Text saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

void loadText() {
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
    translatedTextInput.setText(savedText);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```